# I want to create an Objective-C component with PhoneGap

Tags: android, objective-c, ios, cordova

I want to create a component with PhoneGap that can be used with both iOS and Android. My first thought was PhoneGap, as it helps developing cross-platform applications with HTML5 and JavaScript.

The thing is, I don't want to develop an entire application; I want a component that can be imported in existing iOS and Android projects.

**Is this possible with PhoneGap? Or is this even advisable?**

Comment: I guess you could load a bit of HTML and JS on a `UIWebView`, you could do the same in Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Late response, but since I was looking for the same thing:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_cordova-webview_ios.md.html#Embedding%20Cordova%20WebView%20on%20iOS

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_cordova-webview_android.md.html#Embedding%20Cordova%20WebView%20on%20Android

Comment: In other words, yes it's possible! Thanks!